# bar code scanning with vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, barcode

I am doing on 1 desktop application .
I want to add barcode reading facility in this.
In my app all products would have barcodes in their price tags.
I will use some bar code scanner for scanning.
but i am having no ides about all these.
can anybody give apme sample code or some reference for this?

Comment: Do you have a hardware barcode scanner or do you wan't to use a camera and image processing?

Comment: @TEAM-ALPHA- i will use hardware  device for that..client will give us later...first i have to collect the code. I have searched a lot..but cant get some result

Comment: what interface does the device use? PS/2 or COM (maybe virtual COM over USB)?

Comment: i will use COM using USB

Comment: Are you using TWAIN to process the scanning part? And does the barcode scanners support TWAIN? If yes, you can use ICAP_BARCODEDETECTIONENABLED provided in the TWAIN specification to turn on the feature. http://www.twain.org/scannerdriverdevelopers/specification-and-tools.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For COM over USB you need the COM port number (look in your device manager), lets say COM15
Using VB.net use the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class:

```
Dim comPort As New SerialPort("COM15") 'New com port'
Dim terminatingChar As Char = Chr(10) 'Terminate at vbLF (new line)'

comPort.BaudRate = 9600 '9600 baud speed'
comPort.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII 'Decode the bytes via ASCII code'

comPort.Open() 'Open the port'

Dim myBarcode as String = "" 'Current barcode is empty'

While True'Read chars until the terminating char appears'
    Dim tempChar as Char = Convert.ToChar(comPort.ReadChar()) 'Read a char'
    If tempChar = terminatingChar Then Exit While 'If its the terminating char, exit the loop'
    myBarcode = myBarcode & tempChar 'If not append it to the barcode string'
End While

comPort.Close() '(!) Close the port'

Console.WriteLine(myBarcode.Trim()) 'Trim it and show it to the user'
```

Comment: Note: It can get more complex than this because barcode scanners can be configured with any number of termination characters in that case you need to split the string received yourself in code. This also assumes the barcode scanner is using the default COM port settings 9600,8,n,1 which also can change.

Comment: i edited my post so you can change baudrate, encoding and the terminating char (in this case the space character), i'm not sure if this is valid vb.net code, i stopped programming vb since 3 years

Comment: Your `While` loop is invalid, `ReadChar` return an integer not a Char plus the terminator may be more than one character `CR+LF` is quite common

Comment: ok while loop should (i think) be `While True`, and CR+LF is not important, because you can trim CR and terminate at LF. integer to char is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Most available barcode scanners emulate a keyboard. They come with configuration barcodes that let you configure it to do different things, such as include a carriage return at the end of the code once it scans. So, once you scan a code, it will appear on the screen as if it was typed out (if, for example, a textbox has focus).

Comment: No code is needed. It emulates a keyboard. What this means, is that when the scanner reads in a set of characters, it sends those characters to the computer pretending to be the keyboard. Give it a try, plug a barcode scanner in and open a text editor (Notepad, for example). Scan a barcode and the code appears in the editor window.

Comment: and what should i do for vb.net form?

Comment: you said it'a com over usb, but for ps2 just make a TextBox and register an event when the textchanged, in the event look if its a newline character, and then you got the barcode